# How to shutdown application while bootstrapper class is still running?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, bootstrapper

I am using a Prism UnityExtensions bootstrapper class to start my WPF application.  How do I shutdown the application while the unityextensions bootstrapper is still running?

See my bootstrapper class below.  The `SomeClass` object may throw a custom exception (fatal).  If the custom exception is thrown, I need to close the application.  I am using `Application.Current.Shutdown()` to shutdown the application.

However, the bootstrapper code continues running, and I get a "ResolutionFailedException was unhandled" exception error when setting the datacontext in the `CreateShell()` method.  Obviously, the `SomeClass` method and interface were not registered with the container due to the catch block.

It appears that the bootstrapper code continues running after a call to `Application.Current.Shutdown()` was called.  I need to stop the bootstrapper code immediately following the call to shutdown.

Any ideas how to shutdown the application without creating the `ResolutionFailedException`?

> ResolutionFailedException exception details -->
>   Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "SomeClass", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, SomeClass, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

```
public class AgentBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
  protected override void ConfigureContainer()
  {
     base.ConfigureContainer();

     var eventRepository = new EventRepository();
     Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IEventRepository), eventRepository);

     var dialog = new DialogService();
     Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IDialogService), dialog);

     try
     {
        var someClass = new SomeClass();
        Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISomeClass), SomeClass);
     }
     catch (ConfigurationErrorsException e)
     {
        dialog.ShowException(e.Message + " Application shutting down.");
        **Application.Current.Shutdown();**
     }
  }

  protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
  {
     var main = new MainWindow
     {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(Container.Resolve<IEventRepository>(),
                                              Container.Resolve<IDialogService>(),
                                              Container.Resolve<ISomeClass>())
     };

     return main;
  }

  protected override void InitializeShell()
  {
     base.InitializeShell();
     Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
     Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour occurs, because you´re executing the OnStartup of your Application at this time. I suppose you do it like that:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    new AgentBootstrapper().Run();
}
```

The OnStartup has to be completed, before the App can shutdown, so the bootstrapper continues execution. You might throw another exception to get out of the Run():

```
 ... catch (ConfigurationErrorsException e)
 {
    dialog.ShowException(e.Message + " Application shutting down.");
    throw new ApplicationException("shutdown");
 }
```

And then catch it in the StartUp():

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        new AgentBootstrapper().Run();
    }
    catch(ApplicationException)
    {
        this.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: You got it!!  I do run the bootstrapper from the OnStartup method.  I did not realize the OnStartup method had to finish running before the app could shutdown.  I changed my code per your example and it works great.  Thanks very much for your help.